# Uninstalling Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall, windows-xp

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 along side with Windows XP and then installed Kubuntu 13.04 , both installation took place using USB flash drive.
I now want to uninstall Ubuntu and keep Kubuntu along side with windows XP i tried many times to delete the partition which contain Ubuntu installation and booting files but i dont know which one is Ubuntu and which one is for Kubuntu.
Anyone can help me !

Output:

```
/dev/sda1   *          63    81915434    40957686    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        81915496   625137344   271610924+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        81915498   198774535    58429519    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       286712118   389400476    51344179+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       491508738   625137344    66814303+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       389400576   487387135    48993280   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       487389184   491507711     2059264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda10      198774784   286711807    43968512   83  Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily find out by looking at the outputs of the following:

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep /dev/sd

sudo blkid

cat /etc/fstab | grep UUID
```

Run these from Kubuntu, note the Kubuntu root partition, and then delete the other.

In case you need help identifying partitions, edit the question, and add the outputs.

Comment: /dev/sda8       389400576   48993280   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       487389184    2059264   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda10      198774784   43968512   83  Linux

Comment: I have only Linux and Linux and Linux swap !!

Comment: @mina, add this important info to your question post. It appears you have Ubuntu installed in a single partition, which is ok. If you don't need the data, just re-install in this partition, otherwise create a new logical partition and move your data there. Look here for help : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: So, one must be for Ubuntu and the other for Kubuntu. To find out which is which, please add the outputs of the other two commands.